# Insert a new line after a specific line number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to add a text of line after a specific line in Notepad++ I have found several similar answers through the web but I couldn't manage to adapt the code without recurring.

This is how my text file displayed in Notepad++

```
   This is sample 1
   This is sample 2
   This is sample 3
   This is sample 4
```

This is how I want it displayed after applying regex (Find third row, Insert the text without deleting any other line):

```
   This is sample 1
   This is sample 2
   I insert the text here
   This is sample 3
   This is sample 4
```

The code should not search for any word to get a reference point except counting rows until find the specified one. In addition, it shouldn't repeat in the same text file like "every X row". I'd really wonder how it's done inside a batch file but a regex preferable for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get?

Comment: I tried to adapt this regex `(.*\r?\n){3}\K`  then replacing with `Insert this sample\n`  but this one inserts new text after every 3 lines or rows. I couldn't find out how to run it without repeating every X row.

Comment: Just change `{3}` to `{2}`. Find: `(?:.+\R){2}\K` - Replace: `Insert this sample\n`

Comment: It works like a charm Thank you @Toto How can I accept your solution because it's in comment field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `{3}` to `{2}`to match 2 lines.

- Find what: `(?:.+\R){2}\K`
- Replace with: `Insert this sample\n`